# How to poweroff and poweron a set of hardwares which is remotely maintained?

Tags: hardware

I have 2 server in remote location. They will be power off by end user (power supply or maintainability issue), many end users most frequently makes common mistakes to avoid this confusions, i am trying to know if there is any hardware solution which can solve this kind of problems.

Is there any system solution which can be connected to the Servers power supply and remotely turn on or off. So that end user only switch off slave power not the master power?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you are trying to turn on and off exactly but what we often do is use the impi interface for some things as well as install web or telnet accessible power strip
http://www.digital-loggers.com for example, when you really need to axe power and bring the system back up.

Comment: @dwelch: Assume in Airport, lets say i have 3 PC, for Airport maintainer they shutdown the power of those 3PC, and they just connect the power plug, and remotely we need to now turn it on. Can it be done?

Answer (score 0):

Use a backend controller card for your servers.
These are called RAC (remote access card), MP (management processor) or iLO (integrated lights-out) and are a feature for every server I know of.

With these you can normally

- Turn on/off power
- Diagnose Hardware Problems

The advanced ones can

- Monitor the Hardware and alert by e-mail or snmp-trap
- Give you access to a virtual console via http(s)
- Let you insert virtual media (local DVD/CD/Floppy from your workstation as well as images of these media)
- Monitor Power-Consumption (and graph a historical view)